# VBScript Initialize string

Tags: sql, string, vbscript

I try to initialize a string with an SQL query expression:

```
myString = "SELECT * FROM t_package WHERE t_package.PackageFlags LIKE '*CheckedOutTo=*'""
```

I get the following error: `Unterminated string constant.`

Any ideas?

Comment: @user3857458, Hi Tehila. Have a good day! Tili

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just delete the last ":

```
myString = "SELECT * FROM t_package WHERE t_package.PackageFlags LIKE '*CheckedOutTo=*'"
```